# Too many FFMPEG process

Tags: c#, loops, process, ffmpeg

I have a list of video files and I want to convert them with ffmpeg. This is my code:

```
    public static void ConvertToMp3(String inputPath, String title)
    {
        String outputpath = "\"D:\\Mp3\\" + title + ".mp3\"";

        String _out;
        Process p = new Process();

        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "ffmpeg";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = " -i \"" + inputPath + "\" -vn -f mp3 -ab 192k " + outputpath;

        p.Start();
        p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        _out = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        p.WaitForExit();

        if(!p.HasExited)
            p.Kill();

        Console.WriteLine(_out);   
    }
```

It works fine, but when I call this function in a loop for *n* times, it opens too many processes. I want to open only one process at a time and when it's done, go to the next.

Comment: `p.WaitForExit();` should be making the thread wait until the process exits. Is ffmepg spawning new processes? What happens when you run this command from the command line? Does it wait until the transcode finishes?

Answer (score 0):

What about checking the process count and only executing your code if its less than x ( 2 in example)

```
int process = 0;
foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process myProc in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses())
{
   if (myProc.ProcessName == "process name")
      process++;

   if (process < 2)
      p.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before `WaitForExit`, add this command

```
p.Exited += (sender, e) =>
            {
               // Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60);
               // Thread thread = new Thread(() => callProcess());
               // thread.Start();                    
            };
```

This will work when process finished. I generally use new thread.